# Which Default TBB should use for page and component template after upgrading to DXA 2.0

Tags: web8, dxa

We are using SDL web 8.5 and DXA 2.0 after upgrading from DXA 2.0 CTP to DXA 2.0  our custom page template and component templates did not get updated(example Render Page Content and Default Page Template Finish Actions). We have update content manager using "-importType master-only".Now we can see there is three folder inside Framework -> Developer -> Templates

1. DXA.Legacy
2. DXA.R2
3. DXA.Upgrade

Currently, we are using Default templates which are existing inside **DXA.Upgrade -> Sdl.Web.Tridion.Templates** folder now which template we should use

Answer (score 2):

DXA 2.0 data format is more compact and will probably make publishing a bit faster, I would recommend considering to go to **DXA.R2** to get full benefits of DXA 2.0.

replace your custom DXA template building blocks with the new DXA R2 TBBs and republish.

DXA publication website Page template and component templates uses the **Render Page Content => Generate DXA R2 Page Model** and **Render Component Content  => Generate DXA R2 Entity Model** TBBs.

**Content migration Note:**

Starting in DXA 2.0, content is published in a JSON format rather than in XML and uses the R2 Data Model. After upgrading to DXA 2.0, we strongly advise republishing to the R2 data format to benefit from its numerous advantages. Republishing is not, however, mandatory.

For content that you cannot republish or do not want to republish until a later date, the Model Service Converter is able to convert the content to the format requested by the web application. Content published prior to installing to 2.0 remains in the DD4T data model, and it can still be accessed and rendered.

Refer to my [upgrade blog](https://community.sdl.com/product-groups/sdl-tridion-dx/tridion-sites/tridion-developer/b/feed/posts/upgrading-to-dxa-2-0-from-previous-version-1-7-on-sdl-tridion-web-8-5) may help.